# Index a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an image that has 7 bands with 6938x752 pixels in each band. I want to do some processing on it so am using a python module called RIOS that deals with the reading and writing of the image to let the user focus on the processing. It reads the image in as a numpy array in blocks so that the processing is more efficient than reading in the whole image.

It reads the image in as a numpy array with the shape (7, 200, 200). I want to process the data by pixel so that I have the information from each band for each pixel. Is there a way to index the array so that for I can process just the 7 values (one for each band) for each pixel within image?

The only little code I can provide here is the function I use to read in, process and write the data.

```
def MASKimage(info, inputs, outputs):

    inputs.image1 = inputs.image1.astype(numpy.float32) # Read the image in as an array with shape (7, 200, 200)

    process = * Do some processing on the array which is the 7 values pixel by pixel * # has shape (1,7)

    outputs.outimage = process
```

Comment: It is no clear what you are asking. Can you give an example of the type of processing you want to do. To get the corresponding pixel in each image you would do `inputs.image1[:,0,0]` for the 0th row 0th column and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `np.transpose` and `np.reshape`:

```
inputs.image1 = input.images1.transpose((1,2,0)).reshape(200*200,7)
```

You can just iterate through the image with a single loop to do your processing as each element represents a pixel with 7 bands.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! After some processing I am get a single pixel value. Imagine for example I want the mean of the 7 values. I want to write this to a new image but it requires a 3d array. Can you show me how to reshape this so I can write it back in the same shape as I read it (with 1 band and not 7)?